# Postresql: how to check regex constraint for every item in a varchar array

Tags: regex, postgresql

**One working way** I found so far is:

```
create or replace function check_array(
  p_v varchar[]
)
returns boolean
language plpgsql as
$$
  declare
    v_v varchar;
  begin

    foreach v_v in array p_v
    loop
      if (v_v !~ '^foo.$')
        then return false;
      end if;
    end loop;

    return true;
  end;
$$;

create table tmp1 (v varchar[] check (check_array(v)));
```

Now as initially expected:

`insert into tmp1(v) values ('{"foo1,foo2"}');` works,

`insert into tmp1(v) values ('{"foo1,foo22"}');` fails.

---

But **is it possible to do without the plsql function**, e.g. like this:

```
create table tmp2 (i integer[] check (1000 >= all(i)));
```

It works, because operator [`all`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ALL) is on the right-hand side of the comparison. But I need it on the left side in order to use regex comparison [`~`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html), like that (doesn't work):

```
create table tmp3 (v varchar[] check (all(v) ~ '^foo.$'));
```

Comment: AFAIK you'll need a PL/pgSQL or SQL function for this. I've often wanted commutated `ALL` and `ANY` operators that apply to the left hand side.

Comment: What's the query you are trying to do this in. Typically for these kind of operations the fastest (for postgres and coding) way to do this is to decompose the array into a set using unnest(), do the operation on  a set

Comment: @MichaelRobellard, would you mind explaining in a little more detail, or providing an example? How would you decompose with `unnest()` and then test each set element against a regex?

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution (or rather workaround):

```
select array_to_string(array['423','342','123'],'SOME_UNIQUE_SEPARATOR') ~ '^(\d{3}(SOME_UNIQUE_SEPARATOR)?)+$' ;
```

But you have to be sure that none of array elements contains SOME_UNIQUE_SEPARATOR.